# Confusion about Linux related terms

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gtk, pygtk

I am confused with various terms associated with linux.

> - GNU
> - Gnome
> - Kde
> - gtk2 and gtk3
> - pygtk
> - qt
> - gtk+

I am trying learn application development for ubuntu. I come across with `Quickly`
and i am learning that and i found out that it uses `pygtk`. In their website they are saying it supprts only upto `GTK 2.2.4` and suggest to move to `GObject`. I saw links in developer.gnome.org also for developing applications are they same? 
Which developement tool or method is good to learn and implement

Comment: Quickly is already ported to pyGOBJECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU is a unix-like OS developed by the GNU project.

GNOME is a desktop environment and part of the GNU Project.

Kde is also a desktop environment but independent of GNU.

GTK2 & 3 are versions of GTK+ which is a free library for GUI developement which for example is used in the GNOME desktop environment.

PyGTK is a wrapper to use GTK+ using Python.

Qt is a framework for application developement including GUIs and console based applications which is, unlike the GTK library, crossplatform usable.

Tho I haven't used Quickly myself, it appears that it is more like a platform to include the technologies you need into your project and wrap the project as a whole rather than a programming resource.

Asking for a recommendation what to learn of all this seems to me like the wrong approach. 
Try sketching a simple project idea you want to implement, then probe which tools and libraries you need to do it and then learn those. Getting your hands dirty and trying these is a better way to get an understanding of what these tools can be used for.

*Edit*

On Quickly and GTK3 compability, see [this Question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63127/does-quickly-support-gtk3)

Comment: what about Quickly and development tools in developer.gnome.org

Comment: Actually i am trying to devlop an app in quickly. After seeing compatability of pygtk as i mentioned in question i asked for a suggestion. If gtk3 is not supported why ubuntu still suggesting quickly?

Comment: see update, referenced a question on askubuntu there

Answer (score 1):

GNU is the operating system based on UNIX/LINUX developed by the GNU project.

GNOME and KDE are desktop environment and graphical user interface that runs on top of a computer operating system.

Qt is a cross-platform application framework that is widely used for developing application software with a graphical user interface and also used for developing non-GUI programs such as command-line tools and consoles for servers.

GTK+ (GIMP Toolkit) is a cross-platform widget toolkit for creating graphical user interfaces. GTK 2 and GTK 3 are older versions of GTK+ I believe.

PyGTK is a set of Python wrappers for the GTK+ graphical user interface library.